# WPF. TextBlock and TextBox aligned properly

Tags: wpf, textbox, textblock

What I have when size of `Border` container is wide enough:

```
Name Value NameLonger Value
```

then size of `Border` gets smaller and I have something like this:

Name Value NameLonger V

I used `WrapPanel` and achieved something like this:

```
Name Value  
NameLonger Value
```

It is better but I would like to achieve something like this:

```
Name       Value  
NameLonger Value
```

Is it possible to achieve such thing?

Answer (score 1):

not sure if i totally understand  what you are explaining but based on what i think yiou are describing, would this be what you are looking for?

```
<Border>
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<!--Put your textblocks in here-->
</Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: This solution does not make my couples of <name, value> change positions when the border changes its width...

Comment: I guess I don't understand what your trying to accomplish still.

Answer (score 0):

Use a grid as your container panel. Set the first column width to use as much width as it needs (`"auto"`) and the second column to use the rest (`"*"`).
Place the `textblock` in the first column, and the `textbox` in the second.

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


<textblock .../>
<textbox grid.column="1".../>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: This solution does not make my couples of <name, value> change positions when the border changes its width...